# Best way of binary repository for .NET projects

Tags: continuous-integration, dotnet, repository

I am very to new to .NET projects and I am wondering which is the best tool to store binaries of .NET project. How good to store binaries of .NET projects in artifactory and why? can some one answer generally Any comments can be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend [ProGet](http://inedo.com/proget). If you're familiar with Artifactory you might find this comparison helpful: https://inedo.com/support/kb/1115/a-comparison-artifactory-vs-proget

Comment: Thanks for your comments...do you think artifacory is a best repo for .NET projects @Karl Harnagy

Comment: @pandey "the best for..." is highly subjective, it really depends on what features you need _in addition_ to the nuget artifacts you want to store (assuming here you will package your assemblies with nuget).  Here is another, more complete, comparison of binary repositories.  https://binary-repositories-comparison.github.io/  to know which is best first know what exactly you need and then look for the solution that best fills this need.

Answer (score 2):

It is wise to think about package management early on.

There are multiple options in terms of package management. The 2 largest are [jFrog Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/artifactory/) and [Sonatype Nexus](https://www.sonatype.com/nexus-repository-oss). Both offer support for multiple formats such as maven, NuGet, Docker, npm, ...

If you only have standard requirements, both of these will suffice. If you have specific requirements, it's best to look at a comparison such as [this one](https://binary-repositories-comparison.github.io/) to find out which one has got what you need.

Both of these offer free versions with all the functionality you will need included.

When it comes to choosing one: If you have experience with one, i would suggest taking that one. Otherwise, you can't really go wrong with either one, since both are widely used by small and large teams around the world.